# Can't generate API documentation in l5-swagger

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I'm starting to study swagger.

I'm trying to do the same which is done in a book "**Hands-On Full Stack Web Development with Angular 6 and Laravel 5**".

Using php-fpm bash after typing command "`php artisan l5-swagger:generate`"

I have got this exception in VS Code terminal:

```
root@8e6435be9103:/application# php artisan l5-swagger:generate
Regenerating docs
 
ErrorException  : Required @OA\Info() not found
at /application/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php:39
   35|         $this->log = function ($entry, $type) {
   36|             if ($entry instanceof Exception) {
   37|                 $entry = $entry->getMessage();
 > 39|             trigger_error($entry, $type);
   40|         };
   41|     }
   42|
   43|     /**
 
Exception trace:
 
1   trigger_error("Required @OA\Info() not found")
    /application/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php:39
 
2   OpenApi\Logger::OpenApi\{closure}("Required @OA\Info() not found")
    /application/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php:71
```

And when I trying to open http://localhost:8081/api/documentation url it gives this error:

```
Failed to load API definition.
Fetch errorNot Found http://localhost:8081/docs/api-docs.json
```

I'am using php-fpm bash inside docker.
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem.
Thank you!!!

Comment: your annotation for your action has error. something code you write before action,it's same ```* @OA\Get(```

Answer (score 34):

You have to put some annotations in your code before running `php artisan l5-swagger:generate`. First, go to `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` and add a phpdoc comment block as follow before the class declaration:

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
 */
```

This annotation by itself is sufficient to resolve the issue that you described, but if you execute `php artisan l5-swagger:generate` again you will see the following Exception:

```
 ErrorException  : Required @OA\PathItem() not found

  at /home/nathanael/dev/laravel-projects/laravel-swagger/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php:39
    35|         $this->log = function ($entry, $type) {
    36|             if ($entry instanceof Exception) {
    37|                 $entry = $entry->getMessage();
    38|             }
  > 39|             trigger_error($entry, $type);
    40|         };
    41|     }
    42| 
    43|     /**

  Exception trace:

  1   trigger_error("Required @OA\PathItem() not found")
      /home/nathanael/dev/laravel-projects/laravel-swagger/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php:39

  2   OpenApi\Logger::OpenApi\{closure}("Required @OA\PathItem() not found")
      /home/nathanael/dev/laravel-projects/laravel-swagger/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php:71

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

That's because you must have at least one method in a controller with an annotation that describes a route.
You can easily create a resource in your application to test running `php artisan make:controller ProjectsController -r` and adding `Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController')` to `routes/web.php`.
After creating the controller open it and add the following phpdoc comment block before the index method, for example:

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/projects",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="Display a listing of projects.")
 * )
 */
```

Then, run `php artisan l5-swagger:generate` again and you must see a success message in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to fully auto-generate swagger in Laravel without writing any annotations in your code

https://github.com/hussein4alaa/laravel-g4t-swagger-auto-generate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).