# L5-swagger api documentation: Getting error Required @OA\PathItem() not found

Tags: openapi

After reading these 2 posts here on Stackoverflow:
[How to Solved ErrorException : Required @OA\PathItem() not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59917459/how-to-solved-errorexception-required-oa-pathitem-not-found)
[Can't generate API documentation in l5-swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645172/cant-generate-api-documentation-in-l5-swagger/58664253#58664253)

I still get an error `Required @OA\PathItem() not found` after running php artisan l5-swagger:generate.

This is my Controller.php part:

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *     title="My First API Documentation",
 *     version="0.1",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="info@yeagger.com"
 *      ),
 * ),
 *  @OA\Server(
 *      description="Learning env",
 *      url="https://foo.localhost:8000/api/"
 *  ),
 */
class Controller extends BaseController
{
```

and this is my ProfileController part:

```
   /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *      path="/profiles",
     *      @OA\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Successful operation",
     *      ),
     *     @OA\PathItem (
     *     ),
     * )
     */
   function index()
    {
        return new ProfileCollection(Profile::with('user')->paginate());
    }
```

What am I overlooking here?
If anyone can explain and help that would be great :)

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

The problem occured because I am using a laravel modules package and I had to change a bit of code in the l5-swagger.php config file:

```
'annotations' => [
                    base_path('Modules/Api/Http'), <-- changed the base path to the correct module
                ],
```

I then copied the main Controller.php from App/Http/Controllers to the same Module to also get rid of the occuring `@OA\Info() not found` error after that.

Comment: I think this boils down to swagger-php requiring at _least_ one endpoint. In the case above, it was not looking for annotations in the right path, in mine... I had none, yet.

Comment: Thanks, Xavvey, your solution lead me to fix the issue! :)

Answer (score 7):

When I first installed and configured I was having the same error. Turns out that just @OA\Info is not enough to generate the document. In addition to that, it requires atleast one path entry. After adding an api endpoint annotation it got fixed.

example:

```php
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/api/users",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="An example endpoint")
 * )
 */
 public function getUsers() {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: dont know why or how but it did solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

As per [migration documentation](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/docs/guide/migrating-to-v4.md) you need to import Annotations class `use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;` that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
```

if there are these codes above my index() function, it should be deleted immediately. that's why I got this error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this when migrating to `v4.8.x`, which is when `doctrine/annotations` was removed as a dependency.

You either need to add `doctrine/annotations` as a dependency or change to using PHP annotations i.e.

```
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

#[OA\Info(
    version: '1.0.0',
    title: 'My API'
)]
```

instead of

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *   version="1.0.0",
 *   title="My API"
 * )
 */
```

You can use both types of annotations if you have a lot that you don't want to migrate all at once.

Answer (score -2):

This error typically occurs when using OpenAPI annotations (such as @OA\PathItem()) in Laravel without having the necessary packages installed. Make sure you have installed the darkaonline/l5-swagger package properly, as it provides support for OpenAPI annotations in Laravel.

If you have already installed the package, ensure that you have followed all the setup steps correctly and that your routes and annotations are properly defined. If the issue persists, you may need to review your code and configuration to identify any missing or misconfigured elements.
[image]

Comment: Please share more details, such that others can learn from your answer, and share all details **in text form**